# how to separate rows Group by in sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been working on query as below. (I do use VB.NET 2010 and DB is MsAccess 2007)

```
SELECT 
    sale_details.invoiceno AS sale_details_invoiceno, 
    sale_details.product_code,
    sale_details.qty, sale_details.totalkg, sale_details.Rate, sale_details.subtotal,     
    sale_head.invoiceno AS sale_head_invoiceno, sale_head.suppliername, sale_head.invoicedate
FROM 
    sale_head 
INNER JOIN 
    sale_details ON sale_head.[invoiceno] = sale_details.[invoiceno]
WHERE 
    (((sale_head.suppliername)='Ramkrishna Creation'));
```

Which display result as below:

```
sale_details_invoice|product_code|qty |totalkg|Rate |Subtotal|Sale_head_invoice|suppliername          |invoicedate

5026                | M 1010     | 10 | 2.5   | 270 |   675  |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
5026                | CHIKU      | 100| 25    | 500 |  12500 |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
5026                | F PINK     | 50 | 12.5  | 500 |  6250  |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
4002                | LJ 16      | 80 | 12    | 350 |  4200  |4002             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
4002                | BCH 950    | 50 | 12.5  | 150 |  1875  |4002             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
3598                | L COPPER   | 150| 37.5  | 500 |  18750 |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
3598                | BCH 950    | 50 | 12.5  | 150 |  1875  |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
3598                | CHIKU      | 100| 25    | 500 |  12500 |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
```

I want to break and Display TOTAL of invoice no. Is there any way in SQL OR VB.NET DataGrid Control to display result like below ?

```
sale_details_invoice|product_code|qty |totalkg|Rate |Subtotal|Sale_head_invoice|suppliername          |invoicedate

5026                | M 1010     | 10 | 2.5   | 270 |   675  |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
5026                | CHIKU      | 100| 25    | 500 |  12500 |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
5026                | F PINK     | 50 | 12.5  | 500 |  6250  |5026             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
TOTAL                                                  19425

4002                | LJ 16      | 80 | 12    | 350 |  4200  |4002             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
4002                | BCH 950    | 50 | 12.5  | 150 |  1875  |4002             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
TOTAL                                                  6075

3598                | L COPPER   | 150| 37.5  | 500 |  18750 |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
3598                | BCH 950    | 50 | 12.5  | 150 |  1875  |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 10/08/2014
3598                | CHIKU      | 100| 25    | 500 |  12500 |3598             |Ramkrishna Creation   | 18/07/2014
TOTAL                                                  33125
```

Is there any way to solve this problem by SQL or VB.NET DataGrid control ?. I have been finding solution but I did  not get it yet, Please guys if you do know, Do let me know

Comment: Use a groupby invoice id...

Comment: Can you please write whole query please ?

Comment: Add this: GroupBy sale_details.invoiceno after your where clause

Comment: This will return all your invoices together (same numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either compute your data in a loop in VB or have SQL select the totals. For the latter you will hvae to query the same data again:

```
SELECT 
  sd.invoiceno AS sale_details_invoiceno, 
  sd.product_code,
  sd.qty, 
  sd.totalkg, 
  sd.Rate, 
  sd.subtotal,     
  sh.invoiceno AS sale_head_invoiceno, 
  sh.suppliername, 
  sh.invoicedate
FROM sale_head sh
INNER JOIN sale_details sd ON sh.invoiceno = sd.invoiceno
WHERE sh.suppliername = 'Ramkrishna Creation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  sd.invoiceno,
  'TOTAL',
  null, 
  null, 
  null, 
  SUM(sd.subtotal),     
  null, 
  null, 
  null
FROM sale_head sh
INNER JOIN sale_details sd ON sh.invoiceno = sd.invoiceno
WHERE sh.suppliername = 'Ramkrishna Creation'
GROUP BY sd.invoiceno 
ORDER BY sale_details_invoiceno, IIF(product_code = 'TOTAL', 1, 0);
```

Comment: Just one more issue is : TOTAL shows top of the invoiceno(row), Is there any way to display bottom of the invoice where invoice number changed ? this will clear my all doubt. Thank in advance

Comment: Also when I excute above query I got an error that ---  The ORDER BY expression (IIF(product_code='TOTAL',1,0)) includes fields that are not selected by the query. Only those fields requested in the first query can be included in an ORDER BY expression

Comment: This is strange. I don't use MS Access usually, so I can only guess. UNION ALL is supposed to work such that the first query gets executed and the results from the second query gets added. So the column names should stem from the first query. product_code for instance. Maybe Access names it differently for some reason, such as sd_product_code or product_code_1 or what ever. So try to use aliases, maybe even in both queries: `sd.product_code AS product_code,` and `'TOTAL' AS product_code,`. This should name the column correctly and also do for the title.

Comment: As to only two invoice records: Are you saying the first query gives a different result than you original query? I did nothing more than take your query and used aliases for readability. This should not lead to a different result. Please check again.

Comment: But is there any way to display Total of invoiceno at end when invoceno get changed ?Right now TOTAL shows at top of the invoceno. seems I have come too close just need little alternation. Please help if you do know.

Comment: I find no explanation for this. We select invoiceno and product_code in both selects (where in the second select we fill product_code with the string 'TOTAL'). Then we glue them together and sort by invoiceno and inside invoiceno by 1 for the string 'TOTAL' or 0 for any other string. 0 is smaller than 1, so these records come first, and the total line comes last. I have no idea. Maybe you can add `IIF(product_code = 'TOTAL', 1, 0)` to your select list, just to test whether it evaluates 0 and 1 correctly.